# Writing into RCFile Hive table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to insert data from one Hive table into another Hive table with **RCFile** file format, and that doesn't work as expected.
I tried two methods:

**Method 1**:

```
df = spark.sql("select * from schema_name.origin_table")
df.write.option("compression", "snappy").format("rcfile").saveAsTable("schema_name.rc_table_name")
```

**Method 2:**

```
spark.sql("insert into table schema_name.rc_table_name select * from schema_name.origin_table")
```

Method 1 did not work.
Method 2 worked but did not compress the data.

I tried doing the same thing with Parquet and with Parquet method 1 worked just fine, and method 2 worked but didn't compress, but I was able to solve it by running:

```
spark.sql("set parquet.compression=snappy")
```

However I can't find a configuration parameter that solves it for RCFile.

Does anyone know how it can be done? Couldn't find in the documentation either.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```py
df.write.insertInto("schema_name.rc_table_name")
```

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't compress the table unfortunately

Comment: @dutysloth worth trying 